# disable auto download of files in react native video

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I am using [react-native-video](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video) to stream video in my app. The video starts with paused state.

From `onLoadStart` and `onLoad event` i see the video is started to load automatically even though it is paused. These videos are fetched from an URL, not in the assets of the app.

When i have multiple files in one screen it will take too much space in mobile. I want to keep space taken to minimal.

So i want to load files only if it is played by user by clicking the play button.

Is there a way to specify not to autoload files?

Comment: Maybe you could try keep a state to control, after play click then change the url to correct one and it will start loading? Or after click start, then show the video(default is hide). Just some concept..

Comment: Or you could just one video and have a video name list, to press list change the source you want to play.

Comment: @高鵬翔 thanks. I have now implement kind of smilier things you suggested with state. I think it would be a nice feature of the library to control when the file starts getting loaded

Comment: Yep, I have seen some discussion thread are talking about this in library's issue, but there still didn't have this props or methods, so that suggested something like above.